# "How to place a node in previously recorded position (x,y,z) also in 'same direction'"

Tags: android, anchor, arcore, direction, pose

I am reading an Augmented image which is in STATIC position; on augmented image match I am placing multiple renderable in ARSceneView as nodes also recording local and world position of respective nodes.

Then we try to place the nodes/renderables again from recorded local/world position we able to place nodes but direction of placed renderables differs randomly. For eg initially nodes placed in east to west direction now gets placed north to south even after we read Augmented image in the same direction as earlier recorded.

Is there any way using ARCore which detects direction from scene/camera/pose or any alternatives to place renderables with respect to magnetic north or any static direction.

We tried find azimuth and place renderables but it is not accurate.
Also we tried anchors etc.,

Note : We need direction in azimuth plane.

Comment: Have you looked at [Cloud Anchors](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android)?

Comment: Yesh I have but in cloud anchors it can be only resolved for 24 hrs which is not suitable for my app. So I didnt use it.

Comment: Per [this](https://medium.com/6d-ai/how-is-arcore-better-than-arkit-5223e6b3e79d) article, relocalization is hard. Also note the description on how Cloud Anchors works for Google: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android#how-hosted

Comment: Okay thank you, for my requirement I am now working with Point clouds.

Comment: Hi @Thayananth were you able to achieve the requirement? Could you please elaborate how you made it ? that would help us looking for similar requirement.